# Matlab Fucntion Debug (Error: File: sodifficult.m Line: 1 Column: 28 Function definition is misplaced or improperly nested.)

Tags: matlab

Question: A photon moving at speed 1 in the x–y plane starts at t = 0 at (x, y) = (0.5, 0.1) heading due east. Around every integer lattice point (i, j) in the plane, a circular mirror of radius 1/3 has been erected. How far from the origin is the photon at t = 10?

error: 
Error: File: sodifficult.m Line: 1 Column: 28
Function definition is misplaced or improperly nested.

```
function [ output_args ] = function( input_args )
C=[1,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1;0,1,2,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1]
lx=zeros(1,15);
ly=zeros(1,15);
x=zeros(1,15);
y=zeros(1,15);
t=zeros(1,15);
ttotal=zeros(1,15);
ux=zeros(1,14);
uy=zeros(1,14);
vx=zeros(1,14);
vy=zeros(1,14);
x0=0.5;
y0=0.1;
lx(1)=1;
ly(1)=0;
x(1)=1-sqrt(0.91)/3;
y(1)=0.1;
t(1)=x(1)-x0;
ttotal=t(1);

for k=1:14
    ux(k)=3*(x(k)-C(1,k))
    uy(k)=3*(y(k)-C(2,k))
    vx(k)=-uy(k)
    vy(k)=ux(k)
    i=k+1
    lx(i) = -(lx(k)*ux(k)+ly(k)*uy(k))*ux(k)+(lx(k)*vx(k)+ly(k)*vy(k))*vx(k)
    ly(i) = -(lx(k)*ux(k)+ly(k)*uy(k))*uy(k)+(lx(k)*vx(k)+ly(k)*vy(k))*vy(k)
    if k<14
        b = lx(i)*(x(k)-C(1,i)) + ly(i)*(y(k)-C(2,i))
        c = (x(k)-C(1,i))^2 + (y(k)-C(2,i))^2 - 1/9
        t(i) = -b-sqrt(b*b-c)
        ttotal = ttotal + t(i)
    else
        t(i)=1-ttotal
        ttotal=1
    end
        x(i)=x(k)+t(i)*lx(i)
        y(i)=y(k)+t(i)*ly(i)
end

d = sqrt(x(15)^2+y(15)^2)
end
```

Comment: This looks like a bad idea: `function [ output_args ] = function( input_args )`. You're redefining the keyword `function` as the name of a function. Didn't the Matlab Editor underline the second instance of `function` in red for you?

Comment: it is not a problem. i am asking about debug, not the name of function

Answer (score 2):

Don't have enough rep to comment yet, apparently... but horchler is right, the error you're getting is clearly on line 1. try `function [ output_args ] = function_name( input_args )`.